Module not found error using dvc repro, issues with pandas and pyenv
OS: windows 10
I cloned my teammate's git repo, but when I run dvc repro I get an error saying that there is no module named pandas.
project_path (main)
$ dvc repro
Running stage 'data_collection':
> python3 -m src.stages.data_collection--config=params.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "project_path\src\stages\data_collection.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'data_collection': failed to run: python3 -m src.stages.data_collection --config=params.yaml, exited with 1

When I run the .ipynb files directly, there are no issues. When I run the .py files, there are issues.
poetry install causes issue:
    Warning: Validation of the RECORD file of pandas-2.0.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl failed. Please report to the maintainers of that package so they can fix their build process. Details:
    In C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\de\78\8c\366df10f0aa0cee29394593fcdcf6451a0a21227ba93302f64d2e01b5a\pandas-2.0.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl, pandas/_libs/window/msvcp140.dll is not mentioned in RECORD
    In C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\de\78\8c\366df10f0aa0cee29394593fcdcf6451a0a21227ba93302f64d2e01b5a\pandas-2.0.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl, pandas/_libs/window/concrt140.dll is not mentioned in RECORD
    In C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\de\78\8c\366df10f0aa0cee29394593fcdcf6451a0a21227ba93302f64d2e01b5a\pandas-2.0.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl, pandas/_libs/window/vcruntime140_1.dll is not mentioned in RECORD

I ran poetry add pandas@2.0.0 and now poetry install output is:
$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update

Installing the current project: 

But dvc repro still fails.
The python version is correct:
$ poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.11.1 
Implementation: CPython
Path:           user_path\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\package-name-ZTTWURRI-py3.11
Executable:     user_path\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\package-name-ZTTWURRI-py3.11\Scripts\python.exe
Valid:          True

However, I noticed that python3 cannot import pandas module (or yaml). Perhaps it is because I am using Windows?
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>> import yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

python is able to import these:
$ python
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 

Pyenv version is correct
$ pyenv versions
* 3.11.1 (set by user/.python-history)
3.12.2

However, I noticed this issue:
$ pyenv global system
pyenv specific python requisite didn't meet. Project is using different version of python.
Install python 'system' by typing: 'pyenv install system'

Any advice is appreciated!
